# C# no PasswordChar field missing from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Im writing a c# program using vs2015, however there is no option in the properties field of the textbox for PasswordChar. Im trying to make it so the textbox would show '*' instead of the inputted text.

I have tried manually coding in `mytxtbox.PasswordChar = '*'` however I get the error *"TextBox does not contain a definition for PasswordChar"*

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `PasswordBox` instead of `TextBox`.

Note that you will need to use an attached behavior to enable binding of the value to a `ViewModel` property as described in this [tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!! Been trying to figure this out for half an hour - works, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark this as the answer then. ;)